# Linearly independence of linear combination set

Tags: linear-algebra

Let a vector set $v = \{v_1, v_2, \cdots ,v_n\}$ where $v_i\in \mathbb R^{p}$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$. Assume that $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_p$ vectors are linearly independent and $v_{p+1}, v_{p+2}, \cdots, v_n$ can be described by the linear combination of $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_p$. Let another vector set $u = \{u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_k\}$ where $u_j = [u_{j,1}, u_{j,2} \cdots u_{j,n}]^\top \in \mathbb R^{n}$ for $j=1,2,\cdots,k$. The vectors in the set $u$ are linearly independent. Then, are the following vectors $w_j,~j=1,2,\cdots,k$ linealy indenpendent?
\begin{array}{cc}
w_1 = u_{1,1}v_1+u_{1,2}v_2+u_{1,3}v_3+\cdots+u_{1,n}v_n\\
w_2 = u_{2,1}v_1+u_{2,2}v_2+u_{2,3}v_3+\cdots+u_{2,n}v_n\\
w_3 = u_{3,1}v_1+u_{3,2}v_2+u_{3,3}v_3+\cdots+u_{3,n}v_n\\
\vdots\\
w_k = u_{k,1}v_1+u_{k,2}v_2+u_{k,3}v_3+\cdots+u_{k,n}v_n\\
\end{array}

If not, is there anything I can say about linear independence of the vectors $w_j$?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Any attempt? (:

Answer (score 0):

Take $p=1, n=2, k=1$.
 Let $v_1 = 1, v_2 = 0$, $u_1 = (0,1)$. Then $w_1 = 0$.